# E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu 16.04, and everything has been going fine until my OS threw this error today.

Below is the source code from `/etc/apt/sources.list` for line 54:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
```

I have tried appending `ubuntu` after the `/` and before `partner`, but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas what else to try? I can't run `sudo apt-get update` until this is fixed.

Answer (score 12):

You have not provided the release codename.

For example, for Ubuntu 14.04 (`trusty`):

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Replace `trusty` with the codename of the release you are using.

As you are using 16.04 (`xenial`):

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

You can find out the release codename by:

```
lsb_release -c
```

Just the release codename:

```
lsb_release -sc
```

Comment: At many place over internet and documentation you will get "deb http://archive.ubuntu.co/ubuntu" and "xenial partner or xenial testing" like option after a hyperlink option, and may assume it not to be a part of the command but this is due to the way computer understand the links, always/most of the time it is like "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner"