# Problem during updating Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, updates

I am trying to update Ubuntu 16.04 by using the command

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

But the following error message occurs ---

```
E: Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Why does this happen? Also I am unable to install `gnuplot-x11`.

Comment: Start the `terminal` app from the Unity dashboard, and type `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. **copy** that output to your clipboard, then edit your question, and **paste** the output. Please put `<pre>` at the beginning of the pasted text, and `</pre>` at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766669/e-malformed-entry-54-in-list-file-etc-apt-sources-list-component)

Comment: This is a grandfather question from 2016. Leave open.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear:

```
Malformed entry 58 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You will need to edit  /etc/apt/sources.list and check for the failure.

Comment: how do I edit the file ? please tell me in detail . @ frlan

Comment: You could use a command-line text editor, like `nano` or `vi` (although `vi` is rather complex if you don't know how). Or, you can use a GUI text editor like Gedit, Kate, or VS Code. Any one that you have installed would work, I'd suggest `nano`. Also it is best-practice to use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo nano`