# Unable to install wine on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine

I am trying to install wine but got error as

E: Malformed entry 51 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Details are as follows

```
1   # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted
 2  
 3  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
 4  # newer versions of the distribution.
 5  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
 6  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
 7  
 8  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
 9  ## distribution.
10  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
11  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
12  
13  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
14  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
15  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
16  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
17  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
18  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
19  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
20  
21  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
22  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
23  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
24  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
25  ## security team.
26  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
27  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
28  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
29  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
30  
31  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
32  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
33  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
34  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
35  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
36  deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
37  # deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
38  
39  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
40  ## 'partner' repository.
41  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
42  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
43  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
44  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
45  
46  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
47  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
48  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
49  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
50  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
51  deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
52  # deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main
53  deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
54  # deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
55  # deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
56  # deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
57  # deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
58  # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766669/e-malformed-entry-54-in-list-file-etc-apt-sources-list-component)

Answer (score 1):

As the error points to line 51, this one is not correct. I should be as follows.

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic main
```

Please also note further needed steps from [the WineHQ site](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).