# while installing i got error in ros error in ubuntu 18.05

Tags: apt, ros

while installing ros i get the error

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the contents of `ros-latest.list`? This will make it easier to see why there is a "malformed entry" error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: There was no Ubuntu release in 2018-May (ie. 18.05).  Major releases are *year.month* in format, with some *specialist* releases  using the *year* format; your 18.05 is likely a typo, but ensure you're actually using Ubuntu as there was no May release in 2018.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766669/e-malformed-entry-54-in-list-file-etc-apt-sources-list-component)

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command will fix this issue:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Here is [a bug report](https://answers.ros.org/question/311593/apt-update-malformed-entry-1-in-list-file/)  for the same.