# Apt update error in ros2-latest.list

Tags: apt, 20.04, ros

I'm trying to run `sudo apt update`

And I get this message `E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list (Component) E: The list of sources could not be read.`

Here is /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list content:

```
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main main
```

Here is sources.list content:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64(20200808.1)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766669/e-malformed-entry-54-in-list-file-etc-apt-sources-list-component)

Comment: Sorry, It didn't.

Comment: Since you don't show us the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list` it is difficult to to say whats wrong.

Comment: Is it sources.list file or something else?

Comment: It is a malformed entry in that file.

Comment: I'm new to linux and I don't know the malformed entry there, could u help me find it?

Comment: If you post the contents of that file to your question, someone will tell you what is wrong. That's what everyone is telling you.

Comment: I updated the question with sources.list content.

Comment: Why don't you read comments and your own question? We need contents of another file. You got an error message that something is wrong in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list`. You're  asking to help you to find out what is wrong. Why is it so difficult to provide contents of that file?

Comment: Sorry I told you that I'm completely new to Ubuntu, I didn't mange to access this file at first as I told you. But I did and updated the question with its content.

Comment: @AhmedIsmail You updated with the contents of the wrong file. Look at your error message, it clearly states which file is wrong: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list`.

Answer (score 1):

The line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list` is wrong.

Change it to

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu focal main
```

You can do it by running

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list
```

Ctrl+O to save Ctrl+X to exit.