# In Linux Ubuntu 22.04, can't use the terminal due to the following error code

Tags: updates

```
[sudo] password for mic:
mic@mic-OptiPlex-7050:~$ sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor-project.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I've tried most of the fixes on this site, including removing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and putting it on my desktop.  After following that "fix" I couldn't figure out how to continue.  sudo-apt-update just returns the error above.

I've used Linux for several years, but not really savvy with terminal usage.  I've found fixes that give the default lists, but above my head! What other details do you need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)](https://askubuntu.com/q/766669/)

Comment: The error does not mention `/etc/apt/sources.list`, it is a different file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor-project.list` that you need to address

Comment: Read all error messages carefully. This one tells you *exactly where the problem is*: **in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor-project.list**

Comment: I downloaded the Ubuntu 22.04 Sources List and pasted it into the editor.  Now I don't know how to use the commands at the bottom of the page to save the list.

Comment: I downloaded Sources List for 22.04 and pasted into the editor list.  I don't know how to use the comments at the bottom of the editor to save the list. HOW TO SAVE THESE SOURCES USING THE COMMANDS:
^G Help          ^O Write Out     ^W Where Is      ^K Cut           ^T Execute       ^C Location      M-U Undo         M-A Set Mark     M-] To Bracket   M-Q Previous     ^B Back          ^◂ Prev Word
^X Exit          ^R Read File     ^\ Replace       ^U Paste         ^J Justify       ^/ Go To Line    M-E Redo         M-6 Copy         ^Q Where Was     M-W Next         ^F Forward       ^▸ Next Word

Comment: Organic Marble, I see that file, but what do I do with it? Delete it?